# Is this type of data insertion safe and can stop sql injection in Python?

Tags: python, security, python-3.x, sql-injection

I am learning Database connection from [MySQL Connector/Python Developer Guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html).

This is the code I am using to insert data:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="user", password="password", host="127.0.0.1", database="db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = ("INSERT INTO test(name,email) VALUES(%s,%s)")
data = ("cool", "cool")
cursor.execute(query, data)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Is this type of data insertion safe and can stop sql injection?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html), this is the correct syntax for specifying and executing a query with parameters.  Parametrized queries are immune to SQL injection; SQL injection can only occur when you mix user input directly into the query string instead of separating it out.